# Color first row in a xtable generated table

Tags: tables, sweave, knitr, xtable

I am trying to color the FIRST row of my table. But if I add `\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}` to the FIRST row the colored row will be the SECOND. Indeed it is quite straight forward to modify from the second row down, but I couldn't find any suggestion on how to modify the first.

Please consider the following MWE (variation from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580525/1707938))

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl, xcolor}

\begin{document}

<<do_table, results = "asis">>=
library(xtable)
mydf <- data.frame(id = 1:10, var1 = rnorm(10), var2 = runif(10))
rws <- c(1,3,5,6,7)
col <- rep("\\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}", length(rws))
print(xtable(mydf), booktabs = TRUE, 
   add.to.row = list(pos = as.list(rws), command = col))
@

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

How should I color the FIRST row?

Comment: The question is actually not a duplicate. This question asks how to set attributes of the FIRST row while the other question (still open and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20867670/pass-two-set-of-rules-for-rows-to-xtable)) was about defining different attributes for different rows. Please read both questions carefully. I used the same example just because it helps to exemplify both issues.

Comment: If 1 colors the second row what does `rws <- c(0,3,5,6,7)` do?

Comment: rws <- c(0,3,5,6,7) should do it.